# Как сделать так что бы если в консоле написано слово Tm или Time написовалось время на компьютере

Tags: c#

Как сделать так что бы если в консоле написано слово Tm или Time написовалось время на компьютере.И так что бы я смог сделать это с другими фразами.

Comment: `if (Console.ReadLine() == "Tm") Console.WriteLine("Привет мир!");`. Если что то сложней, то можете сделать `Dictionary<string, Action>`. Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: Неясно нужно просто после ввода Tm выводить время, или же нужна автоматическая замена всех Tm на теперешнее время как по шаблону в какой-то фразе. Четче формулируй вопрос. Голос за закрытие как нечетко заданый вопрос.